# I get `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` while using a seperate thread

Tags: android, ui-thread, android-handler

In my Activity I use a handler

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)  {   
               //do GUI stuff, edit views, etc..
    }
};
```

I also have a `Runnable`, which posts to php and waits for a json response

```
Runnable runnable3 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 
            JSONParserArray jsonParserRun = new JSONParserArray();
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p1", "myParam1"));
            try {
                String link = "http://mylink.com/someFileOnServer.php";
                JSONArray jArray = jsonParserRun.makeHttpRequest(link , "POST",
                        params);
                if (jArray != null && jArray.length() != 0) {
                } else {
                    //either null (because of throwing exception) or empty
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 30000);
  }
```

I repeat the task every 30 seconds, finally inside my onCreate() I creat a thread and passing it the `Runnable`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //other stuff
    Thread t = new Thread(runnable3);
    t.start();
}
```

This code throws `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` even thought I am starting a new thread and passing the `Runnable` to it. The class JSONParserArray works fine in other cases (so no worries there)

However, when I run this method inside the `Runnable`, it is working fine.

```
private boolean hasActiveInternetConnection() {
        try {
            new Socket().connect(new InetSocketAddress("google.com", 80), 3000);    
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("tag", e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please paste the entire stack trace showing the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: @CommonsWare it is being caught and I am printing the exception using e.toString(); here is a copy paste ------- android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: That is not a stack trace. Use the three-parameter versions of the `Log` static methods, the ones that take an `Exception` (or `Throwable`) as a parameter, to actually record the stack trace, rather than throwing away this important information.

Comment: why not use AsyncTask ??

Comment: @tony9099 : asynctasks is simple to use , you will put your long task in the `doInBackground()` method, and then you will update your UI in the `onPostExecute()` method easily, otherwise , you can update progressBar for example by implementing the method `onProgressUpdate()`.All this will not generate the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Check an example of how to use Asynctask while downloading a file from Server : http://wp.me/p3V0Ps-2W

Comment: @Houcine thanks for your time. I know how to use asynctask, however, the documentation says not to do things more than couple of seconds in there, and I am afraid my operation would take more than that (timeoutes ..etc) so I wanna do this the heavy thread way...

Comment: @CommonsWare I honestly have never heard of those, and never tried the 3 parameter thing before. Do you have a direct link or something similar ?

Comment: "I honestly have never heard of those" -- you already have calls to `Log` static methods in your code. You just are throwing out the exceptions. "Do you have a direct link or something similar ?" -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: @tony9099 : no problem dude. Otherwise the doc says also : `AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.`

Comment: Use a AsyncTask. Your code is more complicated that it needs to be.

Comment: @taxeeta thanks for your comment.. this in fact was an old question, and the amount of process currently done in the seperate thread (that you suggest using asynctask for) is somehow huge and takes sometimes more than 5,6,7 seconds.. so using thread is more preferable..

Comment: Are you saying that a async task is slower by 5, 6 seconds.

Comment: What other thread, please share link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Handler.postDelayed()` executes the `Runnable` in the `Thread` in which the `Handler` was created. In your case you create it in your Activity on the UI Thread. So the first time, the `Runnable` gets executed in a separate Thread, but the second time in the UI Thread.

Comment: Your could introduce another Runnable that starts a new Thread. `handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){public void run(){new Thread(runnable).start();}}, 30000);`

Comment: which one I should write inside which ? You mean, remove my   handler.postDelayed(runnable, 30000); and put the one in your comment instead ?

Answer (score -4):

There is another way to overcome the exception.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

In your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: This is a very bad and unsafe practice.

Comment: This is a very bad and unsafe practice.

Comment: This is a very bad and unsafe practice.